# ASP.NET GridView: How do I show a FormView on Mouse Over an item?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, mouseover

I want to show a Form, or a picture, or other details associated with a GridView item when the mouse **hovers** over it. Is this possible? Thanks for any specific info on how to do so.

Please note: emphasis is on HOVERING, not clicking.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article from Matt Berseth: [Master-Detail with the GridView, DetailsView and ModalPopup Controls](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/04/masterdetail_with_the_gridview.html).

The article uses the AJAX Modal Popup Extender control to load the contents of the FormView and display the modal popup. There are a lot of ways to do what you're looking for and this is the quickest to get you going.  It's worth your while to look into a bit of AJAX and jQuery and avoid the extra weight of the AJAX Toolkit but, for now, you should be good using the steps listed in the article.

The example in Matt's article uses clicking but the Modal Popup Extender can be triggered on mouseover.

Comment: Could you tell me which event to handle the gridview mouseover? Thanks.